# Formatting JavaScript code in blade files

Tags: javascript, php, ide, phpstorm, laravel-blade

For example I have code:

```
@section('js')
   var test = 0;
@endsection

@section('js_ok')
  <script>
     var test = 0;
  </script>
@endsection
```

[image: example code]

As you see on screenshot, for section **js_ok** everything is fine and PhpStorm know that this section is JavaScript language, but section **js** is treated like a normal text, not JavaScript (tabs, auto completion etc not working).

I need code like section `js`, so my question is: how to tell PhpStorm that section `js` is JavaScript language?

Comment: Put the codes into script tag.

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman that's just example. I can't put script tag in my code. I want to know is it possible to tell phpstorm that current code is javascript language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it's not possible with Blade files -- you cannot inject another language inside specific blade tag/block.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29254 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.